# Prevent ComboBox from setting the selectedValue to null when it's not in the bound list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this problem. I'm using a bunch of comboboxes with dropdown lists of values we allow the user to set a property too. (i.e. Currencies = "USD, CAD, EUR").

Every now and then, when we load data, we'll find the currency is something not in our list, like "AUD". In this case, we still want the combobox to display the loaded value, and the current selected Currency should remain "AUD" unless the user chooses to change it, in which case their only options will still be "USD, CAD, EUR".

My problem is that as soon as the control becomes visible, the ComboBox is calling the setter on my SelectedCurrency property and setting it to `null`, presumably because the current value "AUD" isn't in it's list. How can I disable this behaviour without making it possible for the user to type whatever they want into the Currency field?

Comment: When you load the data you need to check if the value is in the source and if not add it.

Comment: @Blam Question states that option should not be available in the `ComboBox`

Comment: @Rachel Yes I agree. I was more commenting on the behavior of a combobox.  I will try an answer.

Comment: You should never rely on the quirks of a control to do things like these. Create a separate label to show the current currency and a combox for the ones you allow setting. Your users will never get confused why this particular combox behaves 'strangely' and your UI designer will not need to understand your code before making changes to the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a reasonably common problem.  Imagine you have a lookup list in the database, maybe a list of employees.  The employee table has a 'works here' flag.  Another table references the employee lookup list.  When a person leaves the company, you want your views to show the name of the old employee, but not allow the old employee to be assigned in future.

Here's my solution to the similar currency problem:

Xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <Samples:ComboBoxWithObsoleteItemsViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
// ViewModelBase and Set() are from MVVM Light Toolkit
public class ComboBoxWithObsoleteItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly string _originalCurrency;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
    private readonly bool _removeOriginalWhenNotSelected;
    private string _selectedItem;

    public ComboBoxWithObsoleteItemsViewModel()
    {
        // This value might be passed in to the VM as a parameter
        // or obtained from a data service
        _originalCurrency = "AUD";

        // This list is hard-coded or obtained from your data service
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<string> {"USD", "CAD", "EUR"};

        // If the value to display isn't in the list, then add it
        if (!collection.Contains(_originalCurrency))
        {
            // Record the fact that we may need to remove this
            // value from the list later.
            _removeOriginalWhenNotSelected = true;
            collection.Add(_originalCurrency);
        }

        Items = collection;

        SelectedItem = _originalCurrency;
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            // Remove the original value from the list if necessary
            if(_removeOriginalWhenNotSelected && value != _originalCurrency)
            {
                Items.Remove(_originalCurrency);
            }

            Set(()=>SelectedItem, ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        private set { Set(()=>Items, ref _items, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to do something very similar. I had to create a special binding dictionary that maintained its own copy of the source items list and would add missing indexes to the collection. Had to do some static caching too so that you wouldn't need to keep a duplicate list view for every data-template that ended up binding to the same collection.

Answer (score 2):

Set `IsEditable="True"`, `IsReadOnly="True"`, and your `SelectedItem` equal to whatever object you want to hold the selected item

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
          Text="{Binding CurrentValue}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True">
```

`IsEditable` allows the `Text` property to show a value not in the list

`IsReadOnly` makes it so the `Text` property is not editable

And `SelectedItem` stores the selected item. It will be `null` until the user selects an item in the list, so in your `SaveCommand`, if `SelectedItem == null` then use `CurrentValue` instead of `SelectedItem` when saving to the database

Comment: If IsReadOnly=True, won't they no longer be able to choose values from the dropdown?

Comment: @Alain I thought that too at first, but did a quick test and it still allows users to select an item from the dropdown and changes the `SelectedItem` correctly, so it appears the `IsReadOnly` flag only affects the `Text` property when `IsEditable="True"`

Answer (score 0):

You should set IsEditable of the ComboBox to true and bind the Text property instead of the SelectedValue property.

Answer (score 0):

If IsEditable = false then ComboBox does not support a value not in the list.

If you want user action to add a value but not edit that value or any existing values then one approach might be to put the new value in TextBlock (not editable) and a Button to let them add that value.  If they select any value from the combobox then hide the TextBlock and Button.

Another approach would be to add the value to the list with more complex logic behind that if any another value is selected then that tentative value is removed.   And the tentative value does not get persisted until it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't want to be users to be able to type, so IsEditable seems to be off the table.

What I would do is just add the new value AUD to the Item list as

```
 ComboBoxItem Content="AUD" Visibility="Collapsed"
```

Then Text="AUD" will work in code but not from the drop down.
To be fancy, one could make a converter for the ItemsSource that binds to the TEXT box and adds it collapsed automatically

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution to this problem:

XAML looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <local:CCYDictionary Key="{TemplateBinding Content}">
        <local:CCYDictionary.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxCellStyle}"
                          SelectedValuePath="CCYName" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="CCYName"
                          TextSearch.TextPath="CCYName"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CCYDictionary}}, Path=ListItems}"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CCYDictionary.ContentTemplate>
    </local:CCYDictionary>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- For Completion's sake, here's the style and the datacolumn using it -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxCellStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTextSearchEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <!-- ...other unrelated stuff (this combobox was was a cell template for a datagrid) -->
</Style>
<Column FieldName="CCYcode" Title="Currency" DataTemplate="{StaticResource CCYEditor}" />
```

There's probably a nicer way for the dictionary to expose the ItemsSource so that the Bindings aren't so ugly, but once I got it to work I was too tired of the problem to refine it further.

Individual dictionaries declared like so:

```
public class CCYDictionary : DataTableDictionary<CCYDictionary>
{
    protected override DataTable table { get { return ((App)App.Current).ApplicationData.CCY; } }
    protected override string indexKeyField { get { return "CCY"; } }
    public CCYDictionary() { }
}
public class BCPerilDictionary : DataTableDictionary<BCPerilDictionary>
{
    protected override DataTable table { get { return ((App)App.Current).ApplicationData.PerilCrossReference; } }
    protected override string indexKeyField { get { return "BCEventGroupID"; } }
    public BCPerilDictionary() { }
}
//etc...
```

Base class looks like:

```
public abstract class DataTableDictionary<T> : ContentPresenter where T : DataTableDictionary<T>
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof(object), typeof(DataTableDictionary<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnKeyChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Row", typeof(DataRowView), typeof(DataTableDictionary<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRowChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListItems", typeof(DataView), typeof(DataTableDictionary<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexedViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IndexedView", typeof(DataView), typeof(DataTableDictionary<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion Dependency Properties

    #region Private Members
    private static DataTable _SourceList = null;
    private static DataView _ListItems = null;
    private static DataView _IndexedView = null;
    private static readonly Binding BindingToRow;
    private static bool cachedViews = false;
    private bool m_isBeingChanged;
    #endregion Private Members

    #region Virtual Properties
    protected abstract DataTable table { get; }
    protected abstract string indexKeyField { get; }
    #endregion Virtual Properties

    #region Public Properties
    public DataView ListItems
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ListItemsProperty) as DataView; }
        set { this.SetValue(ListItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    public DataView IndexedView
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(IndexedViewProperty) as DataView; }
        set { this.SetValue(IndexedViewProperty, value); }
    }
    public DataRowView Row
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(RowProperty) as DataRowView; }
        set { this.SetValue(RowProperty, value); }
    }
    public object Key
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(KeyProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Constructors
    static DataTableDictionary()
    {
        DataTableDictionary<T>.BindingToRow = new Binding();
        DataTableDictionary<T>.BindingToRow.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        DataTableDictionary<T>.BindingToRow.Path = new PropertyPath(DataTableDictionary<T>.RowProperty);
        DataTableDictionary<T>.BindingToRow.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
    }

    public DataTableDictionary()
    {
        ConstructDictionary();
        this.SetBinding(DataTableDictionary<T>.ContentProperty, DataTableDictionary<T>.BindingToRow);
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Private Methods
    private bool ConstructDictionary()
    {            
        if( cachedViews == false )
        {
            _SourceList = table;
            if( _SourceList == null )
            {   //The application isn't loaded yet, we'll have to defer constructing this dictionary until it's used.
                return false;
            }
            _SourceList = _SourceList.Copy(); //Copy the table so if the base table is modified externally we aren't affected.
            _ListItems = _SourceList.DefaultView;
            _IndexedView = CreateIndexedView(_SourceList, indexKeyField);
            cachedViews = true;
        }
        ListItems = _ListItems;
        IndexedView = _IndexedView;
        return true;
    }

    private DataView CreateIndexedView(DataTable table, string indexKey)
    {
        // Create a data view sorted by ID ( keyField ) to quickly find a row.
        DataView dataView = new DataView(table);
        dataView.Sort = indexKey;
        dataView.ApplyDefaultSort = true;
        return dataView;
    }
    #endregion Private Methods

    #region Static Event Handlers
    private static void OnKeyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When the Key changes, try to find the data row that has the new key.
        // If it is not found, return null.
        DataTableDictionary<T> dataTableDictionary = sender as DataTableDictionary<T>;

        if( dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged ) return; //Avoid Reentry
        dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged = true;

        try
        {
            if( dataTableDictionary.IndexedView == null ) //We had to defer loading.
                if( !dataTableDictionary.ConstructDictionary() )
                    return; //throw new Exception("Dataview is null. Check to make sure that all Reference tables are loaded.");

            DataRowView[] result = _IndexedView.FindRows(dataTableDictionary.Key);
            DataRowView dataRow = result.Length > 0 ? result[0] : null;

            //Sometimes a null key is valid - but sometimes it's just xceed being dumb - so we only skip the following step if it wasn't xceed.
            if( dataRow == null && dataTableDictionary.Key != null )
            {
                //The entry was not in the DataView, so we will add it to the underlying table so that it is not nullified. Treaty validation will take care of notifying the user.
                DataRow newRow = _SourceList.NewRow();
                //DataRowView newRow = _IndexedView.AddNew();
                int keyIndex = _SourceList.Columns.IndexOf(dataTableDictionary.indexKeyField);
                for( int i = 0; i < _SourceList.Columns.Count; i++ )
                {
                    if( i == keyIndex )
                    {
                        newRow[i] = dataTableDictionary.Key;
                    }
                    else if( _SourceList.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(String) )
                    {
                        newRow[i] = "(Unrecognized Code: '" + (dataTableDictionary.Key == null ? "NULL" : dataTableDictionary.Key) + "')";
                    }
                }
                newRow.EndEdit();
                _SourceList.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
                dataRow = _IndexedView.FindRows(dataTableDictionary.Key)[0];
            }

            dataTableDictionary.Row = dataRow;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unknow error in DataTableDictionary.OnKeyChanged.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged = false;
        }
    }

    private static void OnRowChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When the Key changes, try to find the data row that has the new key.
        // If it is not found, return null.
        DataTableDictionary<T> dataTableDictionary = sender as DataTableDictionary<T>;

        if( dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged ) return; //Avoid Reentry
        dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged = true;

        try
        {
            if( dataTableDictionary.Row == null )
            {
                dataTableDictionary.Key = null;
            }
            else
            {
                dataTableDictionary.Key = dataTableDictionary.Row[dataTableDictionary.indexKeyField];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unknow error in DataTableDictionary.OnRowChanged.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            dataTableDictionary.m_isBeingChanged = false;
        }
    }
    #endregion Static Event Handlers
}
```